# React Native - CheckBox unable to uncheck the "checked" box

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, checkbox

I've  been using React native for a month now but it's my first time to use a **CheckBox** in my application. So, lately I've been struggling to check a specific checkbox inside a **Flatlist** but now I can.

But upon testing my checkboxs I did notice that once I check a specific a CheckBox(or more than 1 checkbox) it doesn't **UNCHECK.**

So, my goal is to make a CheckBox that can check(ofcourse) and also uncheck, if ever a user mischeck or mistap a CheckBox.

Here's my code

```
export default class tables extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            ...
            check: false
        }
    }
    checkBox_Test = (item, index) => {
        let { check } = this.state;
        check[index] = !check[index];
        this.setState({ check: check })

        alert("now the value is " + !this.state.check);
        alert("now the value is " + item.tbl_id);
        console.log(item.tbl_id)
    }
    render() {
        return(
             <View>
                  ....
                  <Flatlist
                        ....
                        <CheckBox
                           value = { this.state.check }
                           onChange = {() => this.checkBox_Test(item) }
                        />
                        ....
                  />
             <View/>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Screen_Shot_Sample]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 1: Make check an `object`

```
export default class tables extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        ...
        check: {}
    }
}
checkBox_Test = (id) => {
    const checkCopy = {...this.state.check}
    if (checkCopy[id]) checkCopy[id] = false;
    else checkCopy[id] = true;
    this.setState({ check: checkCopy });
}
render() {
    return(
         <View>
              ....
              <Flatlist
                    ....
                    <CheckBox
                       value = { this.state.check[item.tbl_id] }
                       onChange = {() => this.checkBox_Test(item.tbl_id) }
                    />
                    ....
              />
         <View/>
    )
}
}
```

Method 2: Make a separate item for each FlatList item

```
class ListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        ...
        check: false
    }
 }

  checkBox_Test = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ check: !prevState.check }));
  }

  render() {
    return(
         <View>
           <CheckBox
              value = { this.state.check }
              onChange = { this.checkBox_Test }
           />
         </View>
    )
   }
 }
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you sir! :)
method 1 works very well in my case.
So if I may ask, do you have any idea how can we pass the items that has a checked checkbox? like if I check table no: 1, then pass it to the next screen.

Comment: @PurpleViolet you can store the selected item in a class variable, for e.g this.selectedItem = item; when check box is true. Now you can use selectedItem anyway and anywhere you want.

Comment: For me, the first method doesn't work. When add `console.log` to `checkBox_Test` I see output only on first change.