# Change Fragment by Clicking to Checkbox in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I recently joined to React Native project team. Due to time constraint, there is no time to learn JavaScript in depth thats why I directly continued the project. My question is how to change fragment by click to the checkbox. So that, when I click to checkbox it changes to another fragment and when I click to uncheck checkbox it goes back to the previous fragment. I found this [React Native - CheckBox unable to uncheck the "checked" box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111540/react-native-checkbox-unable-to-uncheck-the-checked-box)
but it was a little bit harder for me to understand.

Here what I did:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //state to manage the screen visible at a time
    this.state = { val: 1 };
}
renderElement() {
    //You can add N number of Views here in if-else condition
    if (this.state.val === 1) {
        //Return the FirstScreen as a child to set in Parent View
        return <FirstScreen />;
    } else if (this.state.val === 2) {
        //Return the SecondScreen as a child to set in Parent View
        return <SecondScreen />;
    } else {
        //Return the ThirdScreen as a child to set in Parent View
        return <ThirdScreen />;
    }
}
...
<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.button}
   onPress={() => this.setState({ val: 1 })}>
   <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>1st View</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.button}
   onPress={() => this.setState({ val: 2 })}>
   <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>2nd View</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<CheckBox
          value = { this.state.check }
           onChange={() => this.setState({ val: 2 })/>

//This is where my fragment changes 
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}>
                {this.renderElement()}
</View>
```

Currently, I am able to go to 2nd fragment. But I can't go back to the first fragment and uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: why do you need the checkbox if you are already changing the fragment on pressing buttons?

Comment: The task is to make it with the checkbox. But I did it with the button in order to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **[Raju](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8336496/raju) and [Waheed Akhter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4741073/waheed-akhter)**. By combining your answers I found a solution. Here is a solution:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //state to manage the screen visible at a time
    this.state = { val: 1, checked: true };
}
//Toggle state on checkbox change
toggleFragment() {
    if(this.state.val == 1) {
        this.setState({ val: 2});
    } else {
        this.setState({ val: 1});
    }
}
.....
 <CheckBox
          value = { this.state.check }
          onChange={() => this.toggleFragment()}
          onValueChange={(newValue) => this.setState({check:newValue})}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //state to manage the screen visible at a time
    this.state = { val: 1, checked: false };
}

//Toggle state on checkbox change
toggleFragment() {
    if(this.state.val == 1) {
        this.setState({ val: 2, checked: !this.state.checked });
    } else {
        this.setState({ val: 1, checked: !this.state.checked});
    }
}

renderElement() {
    //You can add N number of Views here in if-else condition
    if (this.state.val === 1) {
        //Return the FirstScreen as a child to set in Parent View
        return <FirstScreen />;
    } else if (this.state.val === 2) {
        //Return the SecondScreen as a child to set in Parent View
        return <SecondScreen />;
    } else {
        //Return the ThirdScreen as a child to set in Parent View
        return <ThirdScreen />;
    }
}
...
<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.button}
   onPress={() => this.setState({ val: 1 })}>
   <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>1st View</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.button}
   onPress={() => this.setState({ val: 2 })}>
   <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>2nd View</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<CheckBox
          value = 'checked'
          checked={this.state.checked == true}
           onChange={() => this.toggleFragment()/>

//This is where my fragment changes 
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}>
                {this.renderElement()}
</View>
```

Comment: Once I clicked to checkbox it changed to another fragment, but when I clicked the second time I am not able to uncheck it and go back to the previous fragment.

Comment: you can use the above snippet I have modified it

Comment: Thank you for your response, it only covers half of the problem. I will put the full answer

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //state to manage the screen visible at a time
    this.state = { check: true };
}
renderElement() {
    if (this.state.check) {
        return <FirstScreen />;
    } else {
        return <SecondScreen />;
    }
}
...
<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.button}
   onPress={() => this.setState({ val: 1 })}>
   <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>1st View</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.button}
   onPress={() => this.setState({ val: 2 })}>
   <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>2nd View</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<CheckBox
          value = { this.state.check }
           onValueChange={(newValue) => this.setState({check:newValue})/>

//This is where my fragment changes 
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}>
                {this.renderElement()}
</View>
```

Comment: what to put to newValue ? Becasue it is showing red line

Comment: can you recommend me where to start learning Javascript ? I completely understand what you mean

Comment: I have modified my answer. used onValueChange instead of onChange

Comment: there are so many resources online to learn javascript from like udemy.com, lynda.com, pluralsight.com all of them are great for learning anything

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, your answer only solved part of the problem. I was able only to check and uncheck options. Now I will put the full answer.